# Getting string value of Observable is always "[Object object]"

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have problems to get the string value of my HTTP response. I want to fill the response value in an input field, but the value is always [object Object].
Here is a picture:
[input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V10dl.png)

This is my code:

The request with HttpClient using the HttpClientModule:

```
getString(Example: example): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>(this.url + "/example", example);
  }
```

here I use the Method above:

```
fillInputField() {
    let test=this.userService.getString(this.example).subscribe((result) => {
      this.inputField = result;
    });
```

That gives me the string "[Object object]" and not the String which the observable contains.

Comment: Well it seems like your route does not actually return a `string`. Can you `console.log(result)` to see what is really in there?

Comment: I´m getting a ResponseEntity with the string --> return ResponseEntity.ok("example");

Comment: did you `console.log(result)` ?

Comment: Oh, I can see the problem I´m returning an Object. This is my log: Object { test: "test"} Can you tell me how to get the value from this Object?

Comment: `result.test` will get you the string value

Comment: Okay I could solve it.. I have created a similar object suited to the object which is returned by the response and also change the return type from the method getString to  Observable<Test>